# The use of '#'-sign in haskell program text

Tags: haskell

What do those `#`-signs mean? For example,

```
data Word = W# Word# deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

I tried to google it but I found nothing.

Comment: On the theme of learning how to fish: [Here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords) is a list of all built in operators in haskell. For operators that are just a library function and not built in, you can try [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=hoogle) and [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html). The [info tab for haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) on StackOverflow has a nice summary of common questions and useful resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are unboxed types, [see the corresponding section of the haskell docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html)

They are mainly used for performance or interop reasons(along with the primitive operations that work on them, for example +#)